# Palm Mojo: Object properties

Tags: webos, palm-pre, mojo, mojo-sdk

There was another question with an answer saying that you can use event.down.x to get the x-coordinate of a tap event. It also said that this was not well documented in the Palm Mojo SDK. My question is how can I find the properties that I can use for any given Mojo object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the Mojo debugger and it allows you to print the properties of objects via the command line.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create the JSON for the object with `object.toJSON(yourObjectHere)`. Then you can print it to the log file, screen or where ever you want it.

Maybe there are better ways like `for (var i in yourObjectHere)`, but this is my preferred quick and dirty way.